# Histograms in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram, and i've been doing some searches and trying to find the right code, but everything I try doesn't end up working. This is my code right now,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('gaubg.csv') as f:
       v = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter= ',', dtype="float", skiprows=1, usecols='None')

plt.hist(v, bins=100)
plt.xlabel("G-r0")
plt.ylabel('# of stars')
plt.title("Bottom half g-r0")

plt.show()
```

`gaubg.csv` is a csv file that includes about 600,000 (float, not int) data points that have to do with the color of stars. Every time I run this through python, this is the error message that shows up

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "gaub.py", line 5, in 
>           v = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter= ',', dtype="float", skiprows=1, usecols='None')
>         File "/sdss/ups/prd/numpy/v1_6_1/Linux/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 794, in loadtxt
>           vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
>       TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

I have no idea what that means. I've been trying to fix the code but I'm not sure how. If you could point out the obvious error(s) I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
usecols= 'None'
```

should be

```
usecols= None
```

Or you can skip adding the `usecols` argument altogether.  When you specified a string numpy tried to iterate through each character with the assumption that it's an integer.